# custom java object as parameter to a web service method?

Tags: java, web-services, apache, apache-axis

I am using Axis2 for creating SOAP client in Java. 
The web service is in Java as follows:

```
package com.example.axis2.JavaObject
public class ABCService
{
// private variables
public int changeObj(JavaObject obj)
{
// code
}
}
```

The JavaObject class goes like this:

```
package com.example.axis2.JavaObject
public class JavaObject
{
public String a;
public Date c;
public int d;
// All setters implemented here
// All getters implemented here
public String[] getAttributesNames()
{
String[] arr = {"a","c","d"};
return arr;
}
}
```

The web service client is coded as:

```
package com.example.axis2.JavaObject
public class ABCClient
{
public int callChangeObj(JavaObject obj)
{
ABCServiceStub stub = new ABCServiceStub();
ChangeObj changeobj = new ChangeObj();
**obj.setObj(obj);**
ABCServiceResponse resp = stub.changeObj(changeObj);
System.out.println(resp.get_return());
}
}
```

The bold Java line is giving error that setObj() expects com.example.axis2.JavaObject.ABCServiceStub.JavaObject not com.example.axis2.JavaObject

How do I resolve this error?
Thanks!

Comment: Did you resolved your question? If you resolved that, could you please share the solution with community?